# Instagram API Sandbox User permanently in Pending mode

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm having a problem with the Instagram API sandbox user platform.

Here's the catch:

1. I have two users with a client properly activated each.
2. From the first I invite the second to join the sandbox (Sandbox Invite).
3. From the second user I accept it, everything cool so far.
4. I go to the client from the first user and under Edit->SandBox flap the second user invitation appears as "Pending" and stays that way. It's been 5 hours.

I tried with other users doing the same thing and same thing happens, does anybody bumped into the same issue? It's strange because I have tested sandboxes over and over again and no problem found until now. Thanks a lot for the help guys.

Comment: Same problem here. What was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, it is a problem within Instagram sandbox.

Once the invitation has been accepted the sandbox works fine, you can read everything that user is doing.